# Laravel Backpack select2_from_ajax without Pagination

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

I'm using the Laravel Backpack (v4.0) Admin / Crud. I'm implementing the [select2_from_ajax](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-fields#select2_from_ajax) field on my users table. This field requires that you return a query using the paginate() method.

```
$results = User::where('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_term.'%')->paginate(10);
```

This works, but returns results very slow (10+ seconds). I feel that the paginate() method is what is causing this to take along time to render. If I perform the query directly on the database it takes less then 500ms to return. I have indexes on the email field so that is not what is causing the problem. The users table is ~300k rows.

Does anyone know of a way to alter this so that I can perform an exact match query like below? I don't need it to return multiple results.

```
$results = User::where('email', '=', $search_term)->first();
```

Comment: Interestingly enough if I copy and paste the entire email address directly into the input field it loads relatively quickly. So I dove into the field a little bit further and it appears as if it is querying on every keystroke and for some reason when I type this in very quickly it cause the database to return results very slowly.

Comment: I was able to add a delay:500 to the select2 method in the select2_from_ajax blade template within the vendor folder. This prevented the database query from running on every keystroke and resolve the problem. Interesting that they don't have an option for this within the backpack laravel field.

Comment: That's a cool solution - thanks for the update James. Indeed, we might decide to have an alternative for HUGE tables, waiting 1s after the last keystroke before searching the DB, or something like that. What did you end up using?

Comment: I used a 500ms delay.